# Detect automation browsers on extension install

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to detect if my extension has been installed from a normal browser or with an automation tool. in Manifest v2 it was possible because we could access the window object from the background and we use `navigator.webdriver` property but now in Manifest v3 we can't anymore because of Service Worker.

Is there any alternative solution?

Update:

Here I got the solution in other way. Like we can detect if extension crx file is loaded locally from below method-

```
const self = await browserType.management.getSelf(); 

if(self.installType === "normal"){
 console.log("extension installed locally"); 
}
else if(self.installType === "development"){ 
console.log("extension installed from store"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method one**

```js
let id = chrome.runtime.id  

if (id)
  console.log("id found, not headless")
```

**Method Two**

```js
let checkIfheadless = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage || navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.systemLanguage if (checkIfheadless)   console.log("not headless")
```

**Method Three**

```js
  const phantomJsCheck = function () {
    if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
      console.log("PhantomJS environment detected. #1");
      return;
    }
    if (Function.prototype.bind.toString().replace(/bind/g, 'Error') != Error.toString()) {
      console.log("PhantomJS environment detected. #2");
      return;
    }
    if (Function.prototype.toString.toString().replace(/toString/g, 'Error') != Error.toString()) {
      console.log("PhantomJS environment detected. #3");
      return;
    }
    console.log("PhantomJS environment not detected.");
  }
```

Comment: In my case our extension helps testers so they install it programmatically.
on installation there is some code that i don't want it to run in automated browsers and they opens a blank tab which content script doesn't work in that type of tabs, so sending message from content script won't work.

Comment: try this `chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(checkIfIstalled);

function checkIfIstalled(){
let checkIfheadless = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage || navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.systemLanguage
if (checkIfheadless)
  console.log("not headless")
}`

Comment: SelectorsHub ChroPath Creator
I have edited my answer

Comment: thank you for the solutions but this all will work for headless browser. I am looking solution for non-headless browser. Could you please suggest if there is any solution for the browser where actual automated browser window open and we can see that.

Comment: Here I got the solution in other way.
Like we can detect if extension crx file is loaded locally from below method-

    const self = await browserType.management.getSelf();
    if(self.installType === "normal"){
       console.log("extension installed locally");
    }else if(self.installType === "development"){
        console.log("extension installed from store");
    }

Comment: I am happy to see you found a working solution. your question was not clear. you may edit your question.